# Returning JSON Response in Django

Tags: json, django

I'm attempting to return a JSON response from a query. I've seen examples such as (https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1508), but they don't incorporate passing the HTML template. I'm receiving an error "ictionary update sequence element #0 has length 510; 2 is required"

Model

```
class APCPlats(models.Model):
PlatsProjected = models.IntegerField(db_column='Projected', blank=True, null=True)
PlatsCompleted = models.IntegerField(db_column='Complete', blank=True, null=True)
Month = models.CharField(db_column='Month', max_length=200 , blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Month

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'APCPlats'
```

View

```
def APCChart(request):
   apcdata = APCPlats.objects.all()
   apcchart = serializers.serialize('json', apcdata)

   return render(request, 'apc.html', JsonResponse(apcchart, safe=False))
```

**Solution:**

Create the following class:

```
class DecimalJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
def default(self, o):
    if type(o) == Decimal:
        # Here You can decide if You want decimal to be converted
        # to string or float.
        return float(o)
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        #return o.replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
        return datetime.datetime.strftime(o, "%Y/%m/%d")
    return super(DecimalJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

How to use the class on your queryset:

```
json_data = json.dumps(queryset, cls=DecimalJSONEncoder)
```

Make sure you import the following:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use HTML template with JSON? Are you trying to return HTML as JSON? JSON in HTML? What's the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django view returning json without using template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262278/django-view-returning-json-without-using-template)

Comment: @kichik I solved this issue a while back. I needed to convert queries in Django to JSON to pass into google chart API. All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are trying to return a queryset to frontend with ajax. If this is the case, you dont need to render, all you need is Jsonresponse like:

```
return JsonResponse(appchart, safe=False)
```

Comment: To expound on the solution...

jason_data = json.dumps(list(queryset), cls=DecimalJSONEncoder)